# Jaxb REST JSON to know which param is empty and which param was not sent

Tags: java, json, rest, jaxb

I have a web app with REST services. I have a bean class with JAXB annotations:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "foo")
class Foo {
    @XmlElement
    private String bar1;

    @XmlElement
    private Double bar2;

    @XmlElement
    private Double bar3;
}
```

Then, I send request with JSON:

```
{
    "foo" : {
        "bar1" : "1",            
        "bar3" : ""
    }
}
```

In the request I want: to update value **bar1**, and set null to the value **bar3**

**But**, on the server, I have class' fields both with **null**, I mean, that **bar2** is null, because I didn't send it and **bar3** is null too, because I sent it empty. 
Question is: how can I understand on the server which param was sent for setting null in it, and which param was not sent and I should just to ignore it?

Comment: The following may help:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/04/binding-to-json-xml-handling-null.html

Answer (score 0):

Using property access to fields.
**Example**

```
public class Foo
{
   private Double bar;  

   public Double getBar()
   {
      return bar;
   }

   public void setBar(Double bar)
   {
      System.out.println("I am in setter! " + bar); 
      this.bar = bar;
   }
}
```

now if you will try deserialize

```
{
   "bar" : ""
}
```

output to console is

```
I am in setter! null
```

if you will try deserialize

```
{
}
```

then no output to console - setter wasn't accessed.
So you can check value in setter

```
   @XmlElement
   private Double bar3;  

   public void setBar3(Double bar3)
   {
      if (bar3 == null)
      {
         this.bar3 = new Double(-1);   
      }
      this.bar3 = bar3;
   }
```